# Stationary point processes with arbitrarily slow decorrelation

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics

A point process $P$ (a probability measure on simple, locally finite point configurations $\mathcal{C}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ - I'm restricting to the one-dimensional setting) is stationary when law-invariant under translations. The two-point correlation function $\rho_2(x,y)$ is defined dually by $\int \rho_2(x,y) \varphi(x,y) = \mathbb{E}_P[ \varphi ]$ where $\mathbb{E}_P[ \varphi ]$ is understood as the expectation of $\sum_{x \neq y \in \mathcal{C}} \varphi(x,y)$ under $dP(\mathcal{C})$.

We assume that $\rho_2$ can be represented by a function and stationarity implies that $\rho_2(x,y) = \rho_2(x-y)$. We also assume that $P$ has intensity $1$ (there is a density $1$ of points by unit volume).

Let us say that a stationary point process (s.p.p.) "decorrelates" when $\rho_2(r) \rightarrow_{r + \infty} 1$.

What are the possible behaviours for $T_2 = \rho_2 -1$ (the connected correlation function) ? For example the Poisson process decorrelates immediately whereas the Sine-process ($\beta =2$) decorrelates with $T_2(r) = \frac{\sin^2 \pi r}{\pi^2 r^2}$. Can decorrelation be arbitrarily slow - not only in terms of a scale ($\frac{1}{r}$, $\frac{1}{\log}$,...) but also, on a given scale (say $1- \rho_2(r) = \theta(\frac{1}{r^2})$) ? This is motivated by questions about the possible limits of certain Gibbsian point processes in statistical physics.

More broadly, are there convenient ways of constructing s.p.p. (say, on $\mathbb{R}$) with specified properties [e.g. a given finite numbers of compatible $k$-point correlation function] ?

EDIT. After bibliographical research using a different terminology I found out some relevant references. The paper [On the correlation structure of some random point processes on the line](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/14/38/63/PDF/RPP.pdf) gives examples of decays of order $e^{-\zeta |r|^{\alpha}}$ as well as power-law decays $(1 + r^{\alpha})^{-\zeta}$. In both classes the parameters can be chosen so that the decay is arbitrarily slow, hence my question needs to be rephrased. 
A general way of constructing examples seems to be the use of Determinantal or Permanental point processes, as well as renewal processes. The paper cited above refers to articles by Lebowitz and several other authors who address the more general question of obtaining a certain set of functions as correlation functions.